# How to send E-mail in Java (JSP) through proxy server?

Tags: java, jsp, email, proxy, jakarta-mail

I'm using JavaMail API for sending emails in J. It works fine if I use it over network without proxy, but our college use proxy server that's why it's not working in college. I think our college proxy server supports only HTTP and HTTPS proxies not SOCKS proxy.
I have used

---

```
    props.put("http.proxyHost", "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX");
    props.put("http.proxyPort", "XXXX");
    props.put("https.proxyHost", "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX");
    props.put("https.proxyPort", "XXXX");
```

and I also tried to set

---

```
    props.put("mail.smtp.socks.host","XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socks.port","XXXX");
```

but still it's not working gives error like

---

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.mail.yahoo.com, port: 465;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.SocketException: Malformed reply from SOCKS server
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1972)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:642)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:317)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:176)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:125)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:194)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
    at EmailUtil.sendEmail(EmailUtil.java:33)
    at SSLEmail.main(SSLEmail.java:57)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Malformed reply from SOCKS server
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.readSocksReply(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:319)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:233)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1938)
    ... 8 more
```

I know that JavaMail doesn't support accessing mail servers through a web proxy server. Please suggest any idea about how to reslove it? or else please suggest other mechanisms, API's for sending E-Mails through Java JSP. And Also suggest some ideas for sending SMS through Java (JSP).

Answer (score 0):

Please see this: [JAVA mail API FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#proxy) , although it can use a SOCKS proxy server.

> If your proxy server supports the SOCKS V4 or V5 protocol
>   (http://www.socks.nec.com/aboutsocks.html, RFC1928) and allows
>   anonymous connections, and you're using JDK 1.5 or newer and JavaMail
>   1.4.5 or newer, you can configure a SOCKS proxy on a per-session, per-protocol basis by setting the "mail.smtp.socks.host" property as
>   described in the javadocs for the com.sun.mail.smtp package. Similar
>   properties exist for the "imap" and "pop3" protocols

Comment: I tried for SOCKS Will you please suggest How do I check whether my proxy server supports SOCKS v4/v5 or not.

Comment: As the FAQ says, you might be able to use [Corkscrew](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corkscrew_%28program%29) or [connect](https://bitbucket.org/gotoh/connect/wiki/Home) with your proxy server.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Simple Java Mail](http://www.simplejavamail.org), which is an active open source library with which you can easily configure a SOCKS5 proxy (even authenticated ones!).

```java
Mailer mailer = new Mailer(
        new ServerConfig(smtpHost, smtpPort, smtpUser, smtpPassword),
        TransportStrategy.SMTP_PLAIN,
        new ProxyConfig(proxyHost, proxyPort /*, proxyUser, proxyPassword */)
);
```